# Host aumu AudioUnit

Tags: audio, core-audio, audiounit, audiotoolbox, coremidi

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get kAudioUnitEvent_ParameterValueChange to work with my custom C++ Audio Unit Host app and a third party 'aumu' unit.  I'm loading the unit and displaying the user interfaces just fine.  The audio unit is uniquely rare however, in that the plugin is an interface for an external hardware music device. I'm so close but getting weird results.

1) When I change a parameter on the external device, it shows the updated parameter value in the audio unit's custom UI but not in the generic UI. No event changes are notified.

2) When I change a parameter in the custom UI, neither the external hardware or generic UI detect the updated values and still no parameter change events.  So nothing was getting change values.

3) When I change a value in the generic UI, everything works properly.  I get updated parameter values on both the external device and the custom UI and I'm getting kAudioUnitEvent_ParameterValueChange events.

I'm ultimately trying to get the external device parameters to notify my host app of the event change. My understanding is that Audio Units automatically update parameter values between the UIs and should generate event changes no matter which UI end I use. It seems weird to me that it isn't all being handled automatically. Am I doing something wrong or could this have to do with the Plugin or my Host app?
It seems to work just fine using JUCE pluginHost example but I haven't been able to use JUCE's standalone modules in my project successfully either. Not a lot of Docs on the matter.  I've been at this for weeks and just out of ideas.